# Is it possible to have consonant followed by Uvular sound

Tags: conlang-creation, phonology, naturalism, morphology

I am thinking of creating a language that has a sound system a little similar to Latin, with a guttural feel like German. The people who are going to speak this language are harsh and sound annoyed at all times. At the same time, they are very much attached to their roots; they perform little to no interaction with other races. So there is little influence of foreign languages on theirs.

I thought the sound /q/ would be great here, but the consonant clusters are too hard for me to pronounce. Hence, I am finding it difficult to form words. I am wondering if there is any kind of rule in syllable structure that helps or obstructs this kind of sound system building.

Comment: Are you asking for examples of sequences like /tq/ or /tʀ/? Or are you asking about ways to avoid having those sequences?

Comment: More like how should I use them to make the language more naturalistic, rather than making it stand out in oddish way. Also, if you have some tips on making the language more guttural that would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not quite sure what you're asking. Are you asking how natural languages use uvular sounds? If so, which uvular sounds? /ʀ/ acts rather differently from /q/ (like how /r/ acts rather differently from /t/).

Comment: You are almost there, I am asking how do I make a natural-sounding language using Uvular sound. Plus, what vowels should be dominant.

Answer (score 5):

Uvulars can absolutely go in clusters. As some examples, Georgian **წყ**ალი (***ts'q'****ali*; "water"), Arabic القراءة (*a**lq**ira'a*; "reading"), or Inuktitut ᖃᓂᐅᔮ**ᖅᐸ**ᐃᑦ (*qaniujaa**qp**ait*; "syllabics").